# R data.table subsetting within a group and splitting a data table into two

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table.

```
ts,id
1,a
2,a
3,a
4,a
5,a
6,a
7,a
1,b
2,b
3,b
4,b
```

I want to subset this data.table into two. The criteria is to have approximately the first half for each group (in this case column "id") in one data table and the remaining in another data.table. So the expected result are two data.tables as follows

```
ts,id
1,a
2,a
3,a
4,a
1,b
2,b
```

and

```
 ts,id
 5,a
 6,a
 7,a
 3,b
 4,b
```

I tried the following,

```
z1 = x[,.SD[.I < .N/2,],by=dev]
z1
```

and got just the following

```
id ts
a  1
a  2
a  3
```

Somehow, .I within the .SD isn't working the way I think it should. Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.I` gives the row locations with respect to the whole data.table. Thus it can't be used like that within `.SD`.

Something like

```
DT[, subset := seq_len(.N) > .N/2,by='id']

subset1 <- DT[(subset)][,subset:=NULL]
subset2 <- DT[!(subset)][,subset:=NULL]

subset1
#    ts id
# 1:  4  a
# 2:  5  a
# 3:  6  a
# 4:  7  a
# 5:  3  b
# 6:  4  b
subset2
#   ts id
# 1:  1  a
# 2:  2  a
# 3:  3  a
# 4:  1  b
# 5:  2  b
```

Should work

For more than 2 groups, you could use `cut` to create a factor with the appropriate number of levels

Something like

```
 DT[, subset := cut(seq_len(.N), 3, labels= FALSE),by='id']
 # you could copy to the global environment a subset for each, but this 
 # will not be memory efficient!
 list2env(setattr(split(DT, DT[['subset']]),'names', paste0('s',1:3)), .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: @mnel `.I` and `.N` *can* be used in `.SD`, just have to use them right, see my post

Comment: @eddi -- Indeed. Good spotting.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the corrected version of your expression:

```
dt[, .SD[, .SD[.I <= .N/2]], by = id]
#   id ts
#1:  a  1
#2:  a  2
#3:  a  3
#4:  b  1
#5:  b  2
```

The reason yours is not working is because `.I` and `.N` are not available in the `i-expression` (i.e. first argument of `[`) and so the parent `data.table`'s `.I` and `.N` are used (i.e. `dt`'s).